# Help with proof on finitely generated abelian groups and its product of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, finitely-generated

In my lecture notes, there is a corollary stating that if $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, then there is a surjective homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} ^n\rightarrow  G$ for some integer $n$. It then uses this to state:

> We need to prove that if $H \cong \mathbb{Z} ^m$ is a subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z} ^n$, then $ \mathbb{Z} ^n/H$ is isomorphic to a product of finitely many cyclic groups.

So I have two questions really;

1. How can we even take this quotient to begin with? Wouldn't it correspond to the addition/multiplication of tuples of different sizes?
2. How do we know every finitely generated abelian group can be written in the form of this quotient?

Comment: @Shaun The link is helpful, however it doesn't quite answer the question. I am okay with the proof provided to me in my lecture notes, I simply had questions regarding how some aspects worked. Appreciate the link though thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^m$.  This does not mean that $H$ *equals* $\mathbb Z^m$.  For example, you could have
   $$H = \mathbb Z^m\times \underbrace{\{0\} \times \{0\} \times \cdots \times \{0\}}_{n - m\text{ times}}.$$
2. Use the first isomorphism theorem.  You already know that there is a surjective homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z^n \to G$.  If we let $H = \ker f$, then $G \cong \mathbb Z^n / H.$

Comment: Huge thank you, not sure how the first isomorphism theorem went under the radar since attached to the corollary was a statement about the kernel. Also, would I be correct in assuming that in this case, say for n > m, an m-tuple is equivalent to an n-tuple where every component after the m-th is simply 0?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.